# Obtaining difference in rows between two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data on from two years 2020 and 2021. I want to see which rows appear in the 2020 set, but not 2021, based on a specific value. I tried to create two dataframes and merge but it doesn't seem to work.

```
value = 'EXAMPLE'
filtered_df1 = df_2020[df_2020['column'].str.contains(value, na=False)]
filtered_df2 = df_2021[df_2021['column'].str.contains(value, na=False)]
merged_df = filtered_df1.merge(filtered_df2, on='column', how='outer', indicator=True)
missing_rows = merged_df[~merged_df['column'].isin(filtered_df2['column'])]
```

The above code doesn't return what I expected. It only returns one row. I can see that the rest of the dataframes have been created correctly but the `missing_rows` dataframe doesn't return the correct rows.

Any advice appreciated! I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

After you get your filtered_df1 and filtered_df2 do below -

```
records_in_df1_not_in_df2 = filtered_df1[~(filtered_df1['Name'].isin(filtered_df2['Name']))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Edit: this just returns an empty dataframe but I can see by comparing the two dataframes it definitely shouldn't. Any idea why this could be? I've no idea